# Marginal Probabilities Table

Tags: probability

> The table below illustrates the composition of 101th US congress
>   (chosen 1988). Congressmen are classified into three classes according
>   to the political orientation and the time as a congressman. The table
>   shows the probabilities obtained by treating political orientation and
>   the time as a congressman separately (marginal probabilities). Fill
>   the empty cells of the table under the assumption that the political
>   orientation and the time as a congressman are independent.

[image]

Should i only fill the middle empty cells? Since the events are independent the middle cells will be just $$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {0.614 \cdot 0.090}&{0.386 \cdot 0.090} \\ 
  {0.614 \cdot 0.478}&{0.386 \cdot 0.478} \\ 
  {0.614 \cdot 0.432}&{0.386 \cdot 0.423} 
\end{array}$$

Am i correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your solution is correct. I also do not see any other cells to fill :-)